# Nulltermination of char *

Tags: c, ubuntu, strcat

I am new to C programming and developing under Ubuntu.

I have some sample code:

```
char * output1 ="one\0two\0";

char * output2 = "";    
char * first = "one";
char * second = "two";
char * term = "\0";

output2 = malloc(20);
strcat(output2,first);
strcat(output2,term);
strcat(output2,second);
strcat(output2,term);

printf("%s\n",output2);
printf("%s\n",output1);
```

And the output is the following:

```
onetwo
one
```

The output of `output1` stops, because there is a `\0` in it. But why `output2` doesn't stop printing after i added `\0` ?

What i am doing wrong and how can i add a `\0` to `output2` to make its output print

```
one
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @haccks  Do not see any UB, please point it out.  Note: `output2 = malloc(20);`  I see it now!  `output2 = malloc(20); strcat(output2,first);` is UB because `output2` is not certianly `'\0'` terminated and is followed by `strcat(output2,first);` which expects `output2` to be terminated.

Comment: `strcat` has simple well-defined behavior, fully described on the man page. Reading that carefully and then applying it to your code should immediately tell you what's happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `"\0"` is equivalent a `char[]{ 0, 0 }`. When you use `strcat` it overwrites the current null terminator, copies the values up to and including the first `'\0'`, so this is what happens:

```
// ... are garbage values
strcat(output2,first); // output2 is { 'o', 'n', 'e', '\0', ... } 
strcat(output2,term);  // '\0' is overwritten with `\0` so no change.
strcat(output2,second); // output2 is { 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o', '\0', ... }   
strcat(output2,term); // '\0' is overwritten with `\0` so no change.
```

To make this output `one`:

```
output2[3] = 0;
// or this maybe easier to read
output2[3] = '\0';
```

As pointed out in the comments (and other answers):

```
output2 = malloc(20);
strcat(output2,first);
```

is undefined behavior since `strcat` tries to find the first null character. So just set the first character to `\0`:

```
output2 = malloc(20);
output2[0] = 0; // or '\0'
strcat(output2,first);
```

Comment: Thanks for the small explanation, but when i try this: `strcat(output2,first);
output2[3] = 0;
strcat(output2,second);` i get still `onetwo` as output

Comment: This is the beginning of a good answer, but note the UB of `output2 = malloc(20); strcat(output2,first);`

Comment: @Leviathan: just as before, when you use `strcat` it will overwrite the first null character it finds. This has to be done after.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat(dest, src)` behavior is as follow :

1. Skip up to first `'\0'` in dest,
2. Copy `src` into `dest`, overriding former null-character and adding one at the end.

`strcat(output2, term)` call is being overridden with `strcat(outpu2, second)` call.

**Notice that you have a case of Undefined Behavior (UB) :**

Now, when you write `output2 = malloc(20)`, you're not guaranteed that the allocated memory is null-initialized. `strcat()` will search for a `'\0'` which can be far after the 20 bytes `malloc()` allocated.

You should either do

```
output2 = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
strcat(output2,first);
strcat(output2,term);
strcat(output2,second);
strcat(output2,term);
```

Or

```
output2 = malloc(20);
strcpy(output2,first);
strcat(output2,term);
strcat(output2,second);
strcat(output2,term);
```

Or

```
output2 = malloc(20);
memset(output2, '\0', 20); // Or output2[0] = '\0';
strcat(output2,first);
strcat(output2,term);
strcat(output2,second);
strcat(output2,term);
```

Answer (score 0):

With C strings, the `\0` character always marks the end of the string. So, the string `""` and the string `"\0"` end up effectively meaning the same thing, even though there's an extra byte in the latter.

That is, `strcat(foo, "\0")` doesn't append anything onto `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

the code

```
output2 = malloc(20);
strcat(output2,first);
```

allocates 20 random bytes and then you add the string variable first to that

but output2 points to 20 bytes that can contain anything so there could be e.g. "A\0B\0" in it and strcat would then find A\0 and add first to that.

you need to initalize output2

```
memset(output2,0,20);
```

Comment: Why set all 20 of them, just do the first char.

Comment: well technically your are right of course, just a habit I have because i found it easier when debugging to see when garbage has come into the array and when not.